# linerarization G(x)

Tags: calculus

suppose that a differentiable function $f(x)$ satisfies 
$$\frac{d}{dx}{f(2x^3)}=6x^{11}+6x^5\quad \text{ and }\quad f(2)=4.$$ Find the linearization $L(x)$ of $$G(x)=\int_4^{f(x)}\sqrt{f(t)}dt$$ at $a=2$.

I don't know how to find $G'(2)$. How can I Solve this problem?

Comment: It is {f(t)}^1/2 dt. root of f(t).

Answer (score 0):

Liebniz's rule (an extension of the "Fundamental Theorem of Calculus") says that $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)} F(x,t)dt= F(x,\beta(x))\frac{d\beta}{dx}- F(x,\alpha(x))\frac{d\alpha}{dx}+ \int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}dt$.

Here, $\alpha(x)= 4$, $\beta(x)= f(x)$ and $F(x,t)= \sqrt{f(t)}$.  $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}= 0$ so $G'= \sqrt{f(x)}f'(x)- 2(0)= \sqrt{f(x)}f'(x)$.